# Exchange email archiving in Evolution 3

Tags: ms-exchange

I have successfully setup Evolution 3.2 to retrieve MS Exchange 2007 emails using Exchange MAPI plugin. I was wondering if it is possible to archive MS Exchange emails using Evolution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Create a Folder on the hard drive and symlink it to the folder which you want to keep in Evolution, for archiving.

Direct Evolution to save your emails in that folder. For more information and tutorials [LOOK HERE](http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/)